# How to you calculate currency values, if the "cents" portion doesn't show up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm noob feeling heartache and want to give up. Let's just say I want to add 1,302.22 and ".22" portion, doesn't show up. The next currency I add "44.55" and fifty five cent won't show up. How do I fix this thing without giving me a headache with ".00"?

---

```
double currency = [Amount1.text doubleValue] + [Amount2.text doubleValue];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currency]];
Currency.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",numberAsString];
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem lies here:

```
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currency]];
```

**[NSNumber numberWithInt:currency]** creates a NSNumber object, from an integer value. The integer value you're passing in is `currency`. However, currency's type is a double.

An easy way to think of a `double` is to think of a number that has a decimal point. An easy way to think of an `integer` is to think of a number that doesn't have a decimal point. You can conceptually convert between the two by adding, or removing the decimal point.

Since you are passing a double into a method that expects and integer, you are getting truncation.

For example: the double `1035.55` becomes `1035` when you convert it to an int.

Try changing `numberWithInt` to `numberWithDouble` and see if you have better luck.

Also, don't give up. We've all been there :D

Answer (score 1):

You can condense the code quite a bit:

```
double currency = [Amount1.text doubleValue] + [Amount2.text doubleValue];
Currency.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", currency];
```

Don't give up, you'll get there :)